# How to check if user is already logged in to Twitter

Tags: xcode, twitter, authentication, oauth

I have this code in my SocialViewController implementation file.

```
// Share to Twitter Start
- (IBAction)sharetoTwitter:(id)sender
{

    if(_engine) return;

    _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];

    _engine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
    _engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;

if ([self isLoggedInTwitter])
{
    [_engine sendUpdate:@"Test"];

    UIAlertView *alertTwitterSuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Success" message: @"Your tweet has been posted." delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertTwitterSuccess show];
    [alertTwitterSuccess release];
}
else 
{
    UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];

    if (controller)
    {
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
}

#pragma mark SA_OAuthTwitterEngineDelegate

- (void) storeCachedTwitterOAuthData:(NSString *)data forUsername:(NSString *)username
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject: data forKey:@"authData"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (NSString *) cachedTwitterOAuthDataForUsername:(NSString *)username
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authData"];
}

#pragma mark SA_OAuthTwitterController Delegate

- (void) OAuthTwitterController:(SA_OAuthTwitterController *)controller authenticatedWithUsername:(NSString *)username
{
    NSLog(@"Authenticated with user %@", username);
}

- (void) OAuthTwitterControllerFailed:(SA_OAuthTwitterController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"Authentication Failure");
}

- (void) OAuthTwitterControllerCanceled:(SA_OAuthTwitterController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"Authentication Cancelled");
}
// Share to Twitter End
```

Basically, I have one button that enables the user to post a tweet in my app and within this IBAction, I first log in the user and then once authorized, I want the user to tap the button again and then prompt him/her that a tweet will be posted.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is your implementation of [self isLoggedInTwitter] ? Try using [_engine isAuthorized]

Comment: I have this in my header file: @property (nonatomic, getter = isLoggedInTwitter) BOOL loggedInTwitter;

Comment: Ok... but where do you set it to true ? And I advice you to use the twitter engine mechanism for this check. Look here : [twitter sdk for iphone](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/) step 6 (It worked for me :) )

Comment: Thanks. I tried [_engine isAuthorized] but it's still not loading up..will check that link now..

Comment: It's still not loading any UIAlertView when I tap the button again after logging in to twitter. :(

Comment: I changed my code and it now works! What doesn't work is when you repeatedly tap the button in order to tweet repeatedly too.. :(

Comment: Tweeting repeatedly will not work since Twitter does not allow the same tweet to repeat more than once. Try doing it in twitter and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks like Twitter forbids it.